# On proving that the geometric realization of a simplicial set is a CW complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, proof-explanation, simplicial-stuff

As the title states, I am trying to prove that the geometric realization of a simplicial set $X : \Delta^{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is always a CW complex. I apologize in advance for asking more than one question, but these all seem to belong to one 'package'.

Since my intention is to include this in a final presentation for a course I took which didn't require much category theory, I am looking for the less nonesense-relying argument I can find. The references I am working with are book of May, *Simplicial Objects in Category Theory*, and Goerss and Jardine's *Simplicial Homotopy Theory*.

In the first, the author claims that the result can be easily proven from the fact that the pairs of non-degenerate simplices and interior points form a system of representatives of the geometric realization.

I have proved that each pair $(x,p)$ with $x \in X_n$ and $p \in \Delta^n$ is equivalent to a unique pair $(y,q)$ with $y$ non-degenerate and $q$ interior, but I am failing to see how this implies that the geometric realization is a CW complex. I do realize that a cell has to be the projection of $\{x\} \times \Delta^n$ with $x \in  X_n$ non-degenerate.

In the second book, the authors claim that $X$ is the 'union' of its skeletons (I assume this is to be understood as a colimit of 'nested' subcomplexes) and each skeleton is obtained (as a pushout) by adjoining non degenerate simplices to a previous skeleton (MathJax seems not to support tikzcd, the diagram can be found at the end of page 8 [here](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf)). Since $| \cdot |$ is a left adjoint, it preserves colimits, and so the former shows that $|X|$ is the colimit of the realizations of each skeleton, which are obtained adjoining simplices (in $\mathsf{Top}$).

Here I am failing to find a non-categorical definition of skeleton, all I have found involves left-adjoints or Kan extensions. What is an elementary definition of $\mathsf{sk}_nX$? Even then, it is not clear to me why should't we also prove that $|X|$ has the final topology with respect to each skeleton. Is this a consecuence from the fact that this space is a colimit of the 'inclusion' of skeletons?

I would really appreciate if you could explain any of these proofs with some more detail than the presentations referenced above. I 'know' why this should be true, but I am struggling to fill in the details, and similar questions in this site do not seem to address my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An elementary definition of $\mathrm{sk}_n X$ is: the smallest simplicial subset of $X$ containing all nondegenerate simplices of dimension at most $n$. The $n$-skeleton is obtained from the $(n-1)$-skeleton by pushing out all the nondegenerate $n$-simplices along the canonical map from their boundary into the $(n-1)$-skeleton, and this pushout process defines the attaching maps for the $n$-skeleton of the CW-complex $|X|$.

We certainly should still prove that $|X|$ has the largest topology making all the inclusions $|X_n|\to |X|$ continuous. However, this is a fact about colimits of spaces, not about geometric realization. By the definition of the colimit, a map out of $|X|$ is precisely a consistent family of continuous maps from each $|X_n|$. In particular, a map out of $|X|$ is continuous if and only if its restrictions to each $|X_n|$ are. Even more particularly, a map $|X|\to \text{Sr}$, where $\text{Sr}$ is the Sierpinski space, is continuous if and only if each restriction to $|X_n|$ is. But maps into Sierpinski space are naturally identified with the topology on $|X|$, so we find that a subset of $|X|$ is open if and only if each restriction to $|X_n|$ is, as desired.

Comment: Following your definition, could we define $\mathsf{sk}_n X$ equal to $X$ up to level $n$, and then leaving only the degenerate simplices of each level? (with the (co)restricted face and degeneracy maps of $X$) As for the latter, the definition of CW I am working with needs each skeleton to be contained (as a set) in the next one. I seems to me that this is the case here, but just to check, not only do we have $|X| \simeq \operatorname{colim} |\mathsf{sk}_n X|$ but as sets we have $|X| = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} |\mathsf{sk}_n X|$ right?

Comment: @GuidoA. First question: not quite. You need the $(n+k)$-simplices which are degenerate *at least $k$ times over*, that is, degenerate from a $\leq n$-simplex. Second question: yes, in this case the colimit is a union of subspaces.

Comment: I may be still wrong, but what I was trying to ask is wether we could define $(\mathsf{sk}_nX)_j = X_j$ when $j \leq n$ and $(\mathsf{sk}_kX)_j = \{x \in X : s_{i_1}\cdots s_{i_{j-n}}y, y \in X_n\}$ for $j > n$.

Comment: @GuidoA. Yes, that's right. Your original description seemed to allow all degenerate simplices, rather than the $j-n$-fold degenerate ones as in your new formulation.

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself poorly. Thanks for taking the time to answer both these and the original question! As always, I really appreciate your insight.